# What are these symbols? (\ominus, \oslash but rotated 90 degrees)

Tags: symbols

What are 2-nd and 4-th symbols in the image below ?

- For me, 1-st looks like `\ominus` and 3-rd looks like `\oslash`. But I couldn't figure out the other two.

[image]

Comment: See table "Table 52: stmaryrd Binary Operators" in [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: Always worth a try: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/ (but doesn't help in your case). Interestingly, there are Unicode symbols for exactly the opposite: ⦶ and ⦸

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    $\ominus$, \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ominus$}, $\oslash$ and \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\oslash$}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

### Edit

After seeing campa's suggestion which also considers sub- and superscripts, I will show that this is also possible here using `\mathchoice`:
[image: Result with subscripts]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\obslash{\ensuremath{\mathchoice%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\oslash$}}% inline math
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\oslash$}}% display math
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle\oslash$}}% script
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptscriptstyle\oslash$}}% scriptscript
}}
\newcommand\overt{\ensuremath{\mathchoice%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ominus$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ominus$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptstyle\ominus$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scriptscriptstyle\ominus$}}%
}}

\begin{document}
    $\ominus$, \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\ominus$}, $\oslash$ and \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\oslash$}.
    It also scales correctly when used in sub-/superscripts:
    
    Text: $\ominus_{\ominus_{\ominus}}$, $\overt_{\overt_{\overt}}$, $\oslash_{\oslash_{\oslash}}$ and $\obslash_{\obslash_{\obslash}}$.
    \[
        \textrm{Display: } \ominus_{\ominus_{\ominus}}\textrm{, } \overt_{\overt_{\overt}}\textrm{, } \oslash_{\oslash_{\oslash}}\textrm{ and } \obslash_{\obslash_{\obslash}}\textrm{.}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

All four of these characters are in Unicode and supported with command names in `unicode-math` and compatible packages such as `stix2`

```
 U+2296   U+29B6        U+2298   U+29B8
 \ominus  \circledvert  \oslash  \obslash
```

> ⊖ ⦶ ⊘ ⦸

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}

\[
a ^^^^2296 b  ^^^^29b6   c  ^^^^2298 d  ^^^^29b8
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ominus` as displayed here is a different size from the other operators, and the horizontal stroke doesn't touch the sides of the circle.  In particular, it doesn't match what my TeX installation displays, and what is in the figure in the original post.  Maybe that's just an issue of my browser fonts.

Comment: @LSpice since they're from completely different Unicode blocks, it's obvious the symbols are unrelated despite any visual similarities.

Comment: @LSpice you get arbitary fonts via css, I added STIX2 version set with luatex

Comment: @MarkRansom not really. - and / are older, | and \ added as part of the stix submission, - and \ wouldn't have been re-added at that time as "similar shape". As I show in an image just added, an OpenType math font should have all 4 in matching size.

Answer (score 11):

A modification of [campa's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678588/4427) in order to ensure that the symbols all get the same bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox/\reflectbox
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \binrel@/\binrel@@

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mathreflect}[1]{%
  \binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\mathpalette\math@reflect{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\math@reflect}[2]{\reflectbox{\m@th$#1#2$}}
\newcommand*{\mathrotate}[3][]{%
  \binrel@{#3}\binrel@@{\vphantom{#3}\mathpalette\math@rotate{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\math@rotate}[2]{\math@@rotate#1#2}
\newcommand*{\math@@rotate}[4]{% #1=math style,#2=option,#3=angle,#4=symbol
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#4$}%
  \smash{\makebox[\wd\z@]{\rotatebox[#2]{#3}{$\m@th#1#4$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\obslash}{\mathreflect{\oslash}}
\newcommand*{\overt}{\mathrotate[origin=c]{90}{\ominus}}

\begin{document}

$\ominus$, $\overt$, $\oslash$, and $\obslash$

$a\ominus b$

$a\overt b$

$a\oslash b$

$a\obslash b$

$\overt_{\overt}\oslash_{\oslash}$

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{$\ominus$}\kern-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\overt$}\kern-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\oslash$}\kern-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\obslash$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea with the bounding box (+1), I will definitely steal it though I'll probably define it as starred form (it might be wanted or not). However, I have a small comment: I remember that I introduced the `\@ifnextchar[` to test for an optional argument because using `\rotatebox` and `\rotatebox[]` (i.e. with empty optional parameter) is *not* the same. (Try `\rotatebox{90}{|}\rotatebox[]{90}{|}`.) I also remember not having the time to investigate the issue any further `;-)` but I should look into it again...

Answer (score 8):

From the **stmaryrd** package (symbols used in theoretical computer science):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\ominus$ and $\oslash$ % in LaTeX kernel

$\varominus$, $\varobar$, $\varoslash$ and $\varobslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Once you're using stmaryrd, you can use \obar and \obslash, maintaining the same style as the LaTeX kernel's \ominus and \oslash, rather than switching them all to the \var* versions.

Comment: See table 52 here:  https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf